# Send emails to mailing list using third-party interface

Tags: python, django, email, mailchimp

I have a list (size approx 400) of user details (including email addresses) stored in a database (administered via Django admin interface) and would like to send occasional bulk emails (newsletter) to subsets of these users.

Using Django admin interface I can easily categorise the users to define the subsets and can expose my list of emails addresses through whatever means necessary.

I can write a Django interface to send the emails but this means writing a templating interface, which is something I don't really want to do. I would prefer to generate the email on a third-party provider then send to my list, somehow.

The best solution I have found so far is to use MailChimp. They provide an API through which a MailChimp mailing list can be synchronized with an external list. They provide an interface to create emails and grouping functionality so an email can be sent to subset of the mailing list (again the groups can be managed through the API).

Perfect, almost. I am not particularly comfortable with storing the email addresses on an external host and even less comfortable synchronizing via the API for fear of corruption of my database.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this? Is there some way I can use a third-party interface to create the email (multipart/MIME) message then send to a list of email addresses available from a (secure) web-service, which I can create?

Has anyone else done this? Is anyone using the MailChimp API who has some advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some experience using MailChimp API and must say that it was one of the best API I have worked with. I was using very simple app called [mailsnake](https://github.com/Leftium/mailsnake) to connect to MailChimp API (it actually just wraps your calls and asks MailChimp directly, all this in 40 lines) to build my own middleware.

And answering specific questions: why are you scared about synchronization? It is not very problematic if you want to synchronize list with MailChimp. I am pretty sure that you can only subscribe and update users from your database into MailChimp and completely forget about any synchronization in opposite way. MailChimp will just complain if you try to subscribe or update user which has f.e. unsubscribed from MailChimp, but nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Thanks for your response jasisz. As it happens I have used mailsnake to create a prototype and I agree it is very easy to use and the MailChimp API is very good and well documented. The API includes Web Hooks to update my list following bounces, but you are right - I can just deal with these offline. I cannot find a solution better than that provided by MailChimp but would be interested if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/). They have an extensive API.
I have no experience yet though because Mailchimp fulfilled my requirements so far.

Comment: Thanks Brelsnok. Are you using the MailChimp API?